# Is it possible to disable click label to select on RadioButton and Checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have some forms that use RadioButtons and Checkboxes and they work fine. But I want the user to be able to highlight(select) the text in these controls labels. Instead, when the user tries to select the text clicking on the label, it activates the control itself (RadioButton or Checkbox).

I wonder if it is possible to disable that behavior and have the user click on the icon only (circle or square) to activate it. Clicking on the label should have no effect on the control and should allow the user to highlight the label text, so they can copy and paste it somewhere else.

A possible solution would be to have no label but a plain text besides the control, but it would be nicer if I could just disable clicking the label to select the control.

Comment: You could have the check boxes convert the label to an input box and select the text inside the input.  Beyond that, you might have to look into a library like clipboard.js that copies text to the clipboard when the checkbox is checked.  If you handle the click on the label and `preventDefault` it should keep it from triggering the checkbox/radio

Comment: Instead of using the `<label>` element, just render a text element instead?

Comment: Did anyone solve this problem? I am also facing similar issue. Do not want to toggle checkbox when clicked on label